# JavaScript code not effecting div after jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have a javascript snippet, which intercepts link clicks and turns them to hashes (I know that hash-id isn't in the W3C Recommendations :) )

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newHash = $(this).attr("hash-id");
    console.log(newHash);
    if (typeof newHash === "undefined"){
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    }
    else{
    window.location.hash = "#" + newHash;
    }
});
```

Basically whenever a user clicks any link, it's supposed to get it's "hash-id" if there is none, than it just loads the page regularly.
Now: it works great on my site, footer, header, but after I click an "injected" content

```
$("#container").load(href + " #content");
```

It doesn't work, doesn't return any output to console, alert, nada.

I tried putting the code at the begining, end, footer, in both pages, but nothing works, anyone got any clue how to make it work?

Comment: Have you already tried `$("a").live("click", function(){..})`?

Comment: paste it as an answer so I'll accept, I haven't known this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$("a").live("click", function(){..})`, so that the event listener is binded to all (now and later) `a` elements.

When you use `.click(func)` =`.bind("click", func)`, the event listener is only added for all current (existing) elements, *not* to the elements which are added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use `live()` instead of `click()`, which implies `bind()`.

`bind` only works on current elements selected by the jQuery object, while `live` also affects new elements added to the document.

Check the docs. http://api.jquery.com/live .